# Using different buildscript names in a Gradle multi-project build

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to configure a Gradle multi-project build, but with some of the sub-projects having a buildscript file which has a different name, i.e. not *build.gradle*, but for example *project1build.gradle*. This is because the regular build.gradle exists as well and is used by Android Studio to work on the sub-project in a standalone mode.

Is there a way to define the root buildscript to look for such sub-project buildscripts?

Thanks!

Ariel

Comment: I would strongly advise you to rethink that approach. Not knowing the exact setup it is hard to tell, but this sounds very strange. You are aware of that you can build a subproject at any time with the standard layout?

Comment: Oh, you want it the other way around. In this case too, at least consider my answer as an option. If you are familiar with maven you are basically doublicating pom.xmls here but naming them different and circumventing every standardized process by doing so.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not what I'm looking for. Imagine I have a standard Android project and all is fine. However, only a small part of that code also needs to be built as part of a totally different multi-project Gradle build, which is not related directly to Android. I'm therefore looking for a way to tell Gradle that one of its sub projects has a different buildscript file. Similar to Gradle's -b command-line option, only for a sub-project in a multi-project build. I hope it's clearer now :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, just got an answer from a Gradle core team developer.
Apparently it can be done by defining it in the settings.gradle file like this:

```
include ':foo'
project(':foo').buildFileName = 'foo.gradle'
```

Here's the [link](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/using-special-buildscript-files-in-a-gradle-multi-project-build/13424) to the answer in the Gradle forums.

Answer (score 0):

For your standalone mode I could imagine something like

```
productFlavors {
    standalone {
        //something different
    }
    regular {
       //regular 
    }
}
```

> The product flavor definitions support the same properties as the
>   defaultConfig element. The base configuration for all flavors is
>   specified in defaultConfig, and each flavor overrides any default
>   values.

[reference](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html#workBuildVariants)

This way you could stick with the regular `build.gradle` and still build in `standalone` mode. This setting can be picked up in the `Flavor` pane to the left in your Android Studio (if I recall correctly).

Comment: Thanks, I'm familiar with product flavors but this is not what I'm looking for. Please look at the comment above, I tried to clarify a bit more.